# Can I create translucent + dialog theme in android?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dialog

I want my activity to look like a dialog.

Well, I achieved that using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` 
Now, I also want it to be translucent as it appears in `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`

Is there a a way to mix them both using a custom style??
Please any suggestions, thanks

**EDIT**: achieved something similar with this:
**Now i want to add border like a dialogwindow...how can i do that???**

```
<style name="TransparentDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:windowFrame">@android:color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
      <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
      <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@android:style/Theme.Dialog</item>
      <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    </style>
```

**EDIT**: **Solved this. Check the answer**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally achieved what i wanted with this:

Used this theme for my activity `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`

and gave this `android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"`as background to the root element of my layout

That was so easy!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to combine the two themes together. One thing that might work is:

```
<style name="TranslucentDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">"#33000000"</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Um, it works for me. Are you sure you're applying the TranslucentDialog style to your activity?

Comment: no...stil not working...m applyng what u said  check edited question